# How is the Abomination controlled without Hulk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008

Maybe people reading the comic books can explain this better, but in the movie *The Incredible Hulk* (the one with Edward Norton), *Abomination* is the enemy of Hulk, and at the end Hulk defeats *Abomination*, but after that, they don't say anything about him, even in the *Avengers*.

After the fight between Hulk and the Abomination, Hulk escapes, and they don't say anything about controlling Abomination. So what happens with him?

Comment: Welcome to SHIELD. You may never get to know.

Comment: There is _some_ follow up with the Thor Blu-ray special feature of a Marvel "one shot" called _The Consultant_, where it is explained that there had been a push for _Abomination_ to be considered for the Avengers initiative. It's best watched in full, but the first clip can be [found on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBJMq-isHU4).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The movie universe has not explored this yet, although they probably will in future Hulk and Antman movies. In the comics universe, there are quite a few detainment options for the super villain on the go. They all have various plus or minuses but I'm going to highlight the ones that I think are likely fits for the needs of the movie universe.

The first would be Reed Richard's **Negative Zone Prison Alpha**. This is the most secure of the various prisons in the marvel comics worlds, but I find it the least likely to make the cross over since Fantastic 4 is still not a part of the Marvel movie fold. The prison is run by Richards and is located in a different dimension that should be impossible to escape from.

**The Cube** is slightly more possible, since it is run by SHIELD. However, the plotlines in the comics that have to do with that facility are ill suited to the movies. They may keep the name and lose the plotlines of moral ambiguous mind-controlling of villains.

It seems more likely that they would use something like the **The Raft** or **The Vault** which have no particular story baggage that go along with them. Both were superhuman prisons that lasted for quite a while, although both were eventually destroyed. They would have to hand wave some SHEILD or Stark tech in that would nullify powers, but they could do that with any of the movies.

The prison that I would say would be the easiest, and thus the most likely, would be Pym's **The Big House**. Pym basically created a shrink ray based off his Giantman research that allowed him to shrink down the inmates. Since shrinking is a cheap effect to do and it's instantly graspable by audiences without a ton of exposition, this seems like a perfect fit for the movies.

The final thing that could happen is based around the SHIELD TV show. Since we don't know the plot and SHIELD is typically tasked with taking care of metahuman threats, it is possible that we see the villains' containment options as a part of that show.

So, basically, something is being done with the bad guys to keep them from running around all the time and we have no idea what it is. Yet.

Comment: Great, and is one of this prisons really used against Abomination in the comic books?

Comment: @eLRuLL Abomination was held by the military for a while, but he normally ended up knocked out for years after a battle with the Hulk or at loose ends. He's a silver age character so his story lines are a bit on the whimsical side. He was kept at the Raft during the breakout storyline, as well.

Comment: They're doing an Antman movie? Cool.

Answer (score 7):

Agents of Shield mentions him briefly. Coulson uses guarding Blonsky's prison cell as punishment to Ward. Haven't seen The Consultant.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question "What happens to him (Abomination)?", according to "[Marvel One-Shot: The Consultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_One-Shots#The_Consultant_.282011.29)", he is in some sort of prison.  I don't remember if any other details are given.

Answer (score 2):

Coulson mentions he is in the 'Ice Box' at some point in the AoS series.

Answer (score -2):

I think he transformed back into his human form and was detained then  and to control him from transforming again they probably put some sort of collar around his neck

Comment: You _think_? Do you have any sources?